# How to make an image selectable using pixmap and Qlabel?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel, qpixmap

I am trying to show multiple images using `Pyqt5`. It would be nice to make the image selectable within the GUI so that the users can select and copy that image right away easily.

By "selectable", I meant the user can right click the image and then copy it and then potentially paste it to somewhere else outside of the GUI. Just like a normal image saved in a Word. User can select/copy an image in Word and then paste it to somewhere else.

I know for Text in `Qlabel` this can easily achieved by using `self.my_label.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)`. However, it seems for images there is no such method handling it. Is there any way I can work it out for images?

```
import sys
import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QLabel,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget
)
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize


class Display_Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(980,700))
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.label1 = QLabel(self)
        self.pixmap = QPixmap(path_to_my_image)
        self.pixmap = self.pixmap.scaled(900, 900, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.label1.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.label1.resize(self.pixmap.width(), self.pixmap.height())



# Run if Script
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Display_Window()                                                   # Initialize GUI
    MainWindow.show()                                                                       # Show Window
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "selectable"? Do you want to use the mouse to select a *portion* of the image?

Comment: Thank you @musicamante . By Selectable I meant the user can right click the image and then copy it and then potentially paste it to somewhere else outside of the GUI. Just like a normal image saved in a Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass the label and create a menu whenever it has a valid pixmap, then use the system clipboard to copy it.

```
class CopiableLabel(QLabel):
    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        pixmap = self.pixmap()
        if not pixmap.isNull():
            menu = QMenu()
            copyAction = menu.addAction('Copy image to clipboard')
            if menu.exec_(event.globalPos()) == copyAction:
                QApplication.clipboard().setPixmap(pixmap)
            return
        super().contextMenuEvent(event)


class Display_Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.label1 = CopiableLabel(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label1)
        self.pixmap = QPixmap(path_to_my_image)
        self.pixmap = self.pixmap.scaled(900, 900, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.label1.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
```

Note that setting a pixmap on a QLabel automatically resizes it (unless it has the [`scaledContents`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#scaledContents-prop) property set to `True`.
You also should add the label to the layout, as I did in the above modifications.

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. I am a little surprised though that for image this has to make a subclass to achieve whereas for Text it's just one line of code.

Comment: @whj123 A QLabel is a very basic widget, and it provides the *standard* features expected for what it displays. For a text control, the select/copy menu actions are standard almost anywhere: users *expect* that a selectable text in an user interface can be copied. Images are different, as they can be used for a lot of different purposes, so there's no "convention" about their behavior in UI environments. Providing lots of possibilities is pointless for a toolkit, providing only one is useless, and considering that this can be achieved very easily, there's no need for an API.